# How can i update my data in xamarin without closing and opening my app?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a method that makins a grid table and takes json-data from website, but that website's data is always changing. So I need to close my application and reopen it for data refresh. How can I do it without closing and reopening my app back? How can I refresh my page for update of data?

```cs
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    GetTable();
}

public void GetTable()
{
    //It have my codes for create table and get datas from json
}
```

Comment: Add a button to refresh the data on demand.  Or use a timer to periodically update the data.  Add a pull-to-refresh control.  There are many different ways to solve this.

Comment: @Jason I tried add button for it. But my method also creating new rows or what too. So  when i click it its making new empty rows too so its making some issue.Can i delete my method when i click and re-run it ? Is it possible do something like that ?

Comment: If you want help debugging your code, then you need to post your code and specifically ask for help solving that specific problem.  What you actually asked was a very broad, unspecific question that is impossible to give a specific answer for.

Comment: As Jason suggested, u can use timer or add button or pull-to-refresh controls for triggering update. If you do binding to the view, ui update will work with no issues. For list you can use observablecollection this will make sure adding and removing data will reflect in view. If any field update then use property and publish raise property changed event when there is an update.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it like this instead..

```js
public MainPage() {
  InitializeComponent();
  ValidateDatabase();
}




public async Task ValidateDatabase() {
  //It have my codes for create table and get datas from json

  await loadComponentsFromDatabase();
}


private async Task loadComponentsFromDatabase()

{
  // your operation to the database, and render it to the users

  // note that all components must render here and not in InitializeComponent.

  // so all your components must be visible= false until you are here and make 

  // visible = true

}
```